# Finding the maximum area of a triangle when the distance from a point to three vertices is fixed

Tags: optimization, triangles, area, maxima-minima

(1).$P$ is inside $\Delta ABC$ and $$PA=2,PB=7,PC=11.$$Let the area of the triangle be $S$, then find The maximum value of $S$.

(2).$P$ is inside $\Delta ABC$ and $$PA=x,PB=y,PC=z.$$Let the area of the triangle be $S$, then find The maximum value of $S$.

My approach: for (1),considering the fixed $B,C$, we can easily know that the triangle area is largest when the $AP$ is perpendicular to $BC$. By symmetry, we can know that $P$ is pendicular.
Of course, this is not rigorous. How can we show that when the area reaches the maximum, $P$ must be pendicular without partial derivative.

Comment: we can get $S_{\max}=30\sqrt{3}$ for (1).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590262/find-the-maximum-possible-area-of-triangleabc

Comment: @RobPratt This question is not same as you said.

Comment: I did not mark your question as a duplicate, but it does have the same structure.

Comment: Problem 1569 from Mathematics Magazine (April 1999) is to show that, up to rotation and reflection, there is a unique triangle of maximum area.

Answer (score 2):

For the first case

$PA = 2, PB = 7 , PC = 11 $

So we let $P$ be at the origin $(0,0)$ , and we draw three circles $A,B,C$ of radii $2, 7, 11$ respectively.  Now we can select point $A$ to be at $(2, 0)$.

If point $B$ is fixed at $(x_2, y_2)$ , and we vary point $C$ along the perimeter of circle $C$, then to obtain the maximum area of $\triangle ABC$, point $C$ must have the maximum possible distance from the line segment $AB$, and this can only happen if the extension of segment $PC$ is perpendicular to segment $AB$, which is what you stated in the question.  Extending this result to all three vertices, we deduce that in the maximum area triangle, $PA$ is perpendicular to $BC$ , and $PB$ is perpendicular to $AC$ , and $PC$ is perpendicular to $AB$.  Hence point $P$ must be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$.

Now for the given values of radii, if $A$ is at $(2, 0)$, then $BC$ lies parallel to $y$ axis, i.e.

$B = (x, \sqrt{49 - x^2} )$

$ C = (x, -\sqrt{ 121 - x^2} )$

And we have to determine $x$ such that $B$ is perpendicular to $AC$

$ AC = (x - 2, - \sqrt{121 - x^2} ) $

Hence, by using the dot product

$ B \cdot AC = x (x - 2) - \sqrt{ (49 - x^2) (121 - x^2) } = 0 $

Hence,

$ x^2 - 2 x = \sqrt{ (49 - x^2)(121 - x^2) } $

Squaring

$ x^4 + 4 x^2 - 4 x^3 = (49)(121) - (170 x^2) + x^4 $

So that,

$ 4 x^3 - 174 x^2 + 5929 = 0 $

Solving gives the following solutions:

$-5.5 , 6.31346652052679 , 42.6865334794732 $

The valid root is the negative one: $-5.5$

Hence, $ BC = \sqrt{ 49 - (-5.5)^2 } + \sqrt{ 121 - (-5.5)^2 } = \sqrt{18.75} + \sqrt{90.75} $

Therefore, the maximum area is $ \frac{1}{2} (7.5) ( \sqrt{18.75} + \sqrt{90.75} ) = 30 \sqrt{3} $

Comment: If point $B$ is fixed , we  get point $PC$must  be perpendicular to segment $AB$. But, how can we deduce that in the
maximum area triangle, $PA$ is
perpendicular to $BC$, and $PB$ is
perpendicular to $AC$, which is not easy to get.

Comment: What applies to point $C$ applies also to point $A$ and point $B$. If $PA$ was not perpendicular to $BC$ then we can get a triangle of more area if $A$ is moved so that $PA$ is perpendicular to $BC$.  So in conclusion, segments $PA, PB, PC$ must be perpendicular to $BC, AC, AB$ respectively.

Comment: I konw what you said, but when you move the piont $A$ such that $PA$ is perpendicular to $BC$, then $PC$ maybe not perpendicular to $AB$.

Comment: That's why we have to arrange $A,B,C$ such that the said condition is maintained.

Comment: How do we ensure that after gradual adjustment, point C is orthocenter？

Comment: No.  It is not point $C$ , it is point $P$ that is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$

Comment: yep, I mean how do we ensure that after gradual adjustment, point P is orthogonal center?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143128/discussion-between-glorious-erin-and-mr-he).

Comment: I is easy to get when $P$ is orthocenter, we can not  move $P$ such that get a more area.

Comment: But it is not easy to say after gradual adjustment, point $C$ converges to the orthocenter.

Comment: I don't know what you're saying.  I don't understand it.  I have nothing to add to what I already said.

Comment: Note that $3.75\sqrt{192} = 30\sqrt{3}$, and numerical optimization confirms this maximum, even without enforcing perpendicularity.

Comment: Thank you.  I will change my final answer to $30 \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: For the second part, if the largest radius is scaled to $1$ and the other two radii satisfy $0<r_1<r_2<1$, the corresponding cubic equation is $2x^3 − (r_1^2 + r_2^2 + 1)x^2 + (r_1 r_2)^2 = 0$.  By the intermediate value theorem, it has a unique solution between $-r_1$ and $0$.